# Select Zend Db with array

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

What's the correct syntax to select multiple rows through an array using Zend ? So basically fetch all the data that has name `$a OR $b` etc..depending on number of array elements. I can't figure it out.......

```
public function selectRow($array) 
{
    $data = $this->table->select()
                        ->where('name = ?', $array);
    return $this->table->fetchAll($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `IN clause` for that. So try,

```
$data = $this->table->select()
                    ->where('name IN (?)', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `orWhere()` in the Zend_Db_Select. Check the manual [Zend_Db_Select::where()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where).

```
public function selectRow($array) 
{
    $data = $this->table->select()
                        ->where('name = ?', $array)
                        ->orWhere('address = ?', $anotherarray);
    return $this->table->fetchAll($data);
}
```

- it would be better to use `IN` and `NOT IN` when the where condition contains array of values